# How to get the IP address of incoming connection in custom PAM module

Tags: python, django, bash, ssh, pam

I am using PAM authentication to authenticate with my linux server. I have created a view on my website through Apache2 where I can use python to manually validate each login through a web shell with facial recognition and two factor authentication. This is working, but I can't seem to recover the IP address of the incoming connection. I need a way to find the IP address of my connection to the server before SSH is connected, in the PAM module which is running Python. I would like to use bash for this.

I am trying to execute commands to recover the IP address, I tried using "who" and other commands to see incoming SSH connections to no avail. I also tried using "echo $PAM_RHOST" and "$SSH_CLIENT" and "$SSH_CONNECTION" with no success.

Comment: Have you considered the approach provided in the answer to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127432/logging-ssh-access-attempts) ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the auth.log which seems to work perfectly. All I had to do was reverse the log and get the last IP. The below code also collects unique IPs in order of the last login.

`

```
output = run_command('sudo tail -500 /var/log/auth.log')
op = output.split('\n')
op.reverse()
output = '\n'.join(op)

def unique(thelist):
    u = []
    for i in thelist:
        if i not in u: u.append(i)
    return u

ips = unique(re.findall('Accepted publickey for user from ([\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+)', output))
ip = ips[0]
print(ip) # The last IP
```

`